# What's wrong with this mathematica Return[]?

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica, return

I'm trying to figure out how to use `Return[]` inside an Array definition. To learn this, I'm trying to create an Array of length 5 where every element is the number 10. Here is my code:

```
Array[Function[Return[10];], 5]
```

Here is the output:

```
{Return[10], Return[10], Return[10], Return[10], Return[10]}
```

What went wrong? Why doesn't `Return[10]` resolve to plane old simple 10?

Comment: Cuz you used `[Function[Return[10]], 5]`, hence the 5 `[Return[10]`

Comment: So from my perspective i'm writting a function and that function returns a value and that value is 5. Why isn't that correct? how would you use a return statment in this case. I'm used to Java and javascript where (function(){return 5;})() would get the job done.

Comment: This is a case use for `Return[]` .. `Print@Do[For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
    If[i > 5,
     Return[3],
     Print@i]], {10}];`

Comment: Please read [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534324/how-does-return-work)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to specify which Head to Return from with a [second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6757/121):

```
Array[Function[Return[10, CompoundExpression];], 5]
```

> ```
> {10, 10, 10, 10, 10}
> ```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534549/618728) by Leonid Shifrin for a description of the basic function of `Return`.

See this fine self Q&A for further exploration of the second argument (which is nearly undocumented):

[What can be used as the second argument to Return on your own functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/121)